# ASP code-throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to ASP coding.  I have tried to code 1 page in ASP and run that directly online in a webite which has other asp pages working completely fine.

The code in that page is as below.  Please someone help me.

```
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.To="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
```

Comment: Is some CDO library or product (like Outlook) installed on the server?   Do you get an error when you try to create the object or when you try to send it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting a dll named CDO is not registered.

Try using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32 to register the dll you are trying to use and see if that resolves your error.